# Sorted list based on amount of equal array values in MongoDB

Tags: database, mongodb

I have a simple document structure as followed:

```
{ name: string,
  words: [string]
}
```

I have another string array and would like to generate a sorted list, based on the number of values in the words array that are also in the given array.

for example based on the following data:

```
[{ name: "jason"
  words:["a", "b", "c", "d"]
},
{ name: "thomas"
  words:["a", "b", "c", "u"]
}
{ name: "michael"
  words:["a", "b", "o", "p",]
}]
```

The result i wish to achieve based on the input `["a","b","c","d"]` would be:

```
[
{name: "jason", amount: 4},
{name: "thomas", amount: 3}
{name: "michael", amount: 2}
]
```

The amount key is a nice to have.

Can this be done in a single Mongo-Command?

Comment: db.yourcollection.aggregate([
   {
      $project: {
         name: 1,
         amount: { $size: "$words" }
      }
   }
] )

Comment: How does this command take the input into account?

Comment: @Satya I realise the example might have been confusing, i clarified it

Comment: this command takes your array, processes each record , applies size operator on words array ,

Comment: That is not what i asked, the amount is not the amount of values in the words-array, but the amount of values words-array which also occur in the input array. Please read the question better.